# Eclipse (2023-12) + Buildship - Incorrect classpath when importing test artifact from project library

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, buildship

Basically I have 2 projects .

- Lib2 contains code and test utils. These test utils are classes that should be made available to other projects to instrument their tests.
- Lib3 has some code (that's using Lib2) and tests that uses the test utils from Lib2 (in this case it's a library, but the problem arises when it's an 'application' as well)

When the Lib3 project is imported/refreshed, eclipse generates a wrong classpath, basically it includes Lib2 in the following way:

[image]

As you can see it's **only visible to tests sources** BUT **withtout test code**.
The result is that it's totally useless, since I need part of it to instrument the tests and part of it for the code. **So, all the import fails** (in main and in test).

Relevant gradle configuration:

Lib2:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

//Test Utils Part
sourceSets {
  testUtils {
    compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
  }
  test {
    compileClasspath += sourceSets.testUtils.output
    runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.testUtils.output
  }
}

/*
 * To compile testUtils sourceSet we need to exends the configuration for the 'main' sourceSet.
 * And, since we define dependencies only for testUtils, test must have to extends from it.
 */
configurations {
    testUtilsImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
    testUtilsRuntime.extendsFrom runtime
    testCompile.extendsFrom testUtilsImplementation
    testImplementation.extendsFrom testUtilsImplementation
}

configurations {
    testUtilsArtifacts.extendsFrom testUtilsImplementation
}

task testUtilsJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier.set("test")
    from sourceSets.testUtils.output
}

artifacts {
    testUtilsArtifacts testUtilsJar
}

// End test utils part
```

Lib3:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
     mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
      /*Leo*/
    api project(":Lib2")
    testImplementation project(path: ":Lib2", configuration: 'testUtilsArtifacts')    
 }
```

and settings.gradle

```
include (":Lib2")
project(":Lib2").projectDir = file("../Lib2")
```

It seems a pretty basic configuration, I don't understand why it doesn't work anymore. I believe that I should tweak something using the eclipse plugin but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: In the `Lib2` project in its _Java Build Path_, tab _Order and Export_, are the test sources exported (the checkbox has to be checked)?

Comment: Yes, they are. They are selected by default and cannot be unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Gradle Forums, I've got the [following answer from Ole Osterhagen](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/eclipse-2023-12-buildship-incorrect-classpath-when-importing-test-utils-from-project-library/47970/3) which works for me:

> In order to expose test classes to dependent projects, you have to
> append this to your `build.gradle` of **Lib2**:
>
> ```
> eclipse {
>     classpath {
>         containsTestFixtures = true
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> After a refresh the property without test code for the dependency from
> Lib3 to Lib2 should disappear.
>
> Unfortunately, the other property Visible only for test sources
> requires an ugly workaround in `build.gradle` of **Lib3**:
>
> ```
> eclipse {
>     classpath {
>         file {
>             whenMerged {
>                 // the path '/Lib2' may need to be adjusted to your actual directory structure
>                 entries.findAll { it.path == '/Lib2' }.each { it.entryAttributes['test'] = 'false' }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> See also [EclipseClasspath](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html) in the DSL reference.

Comment: You got the answer from whom? By the way, `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` is not needed in your question, but in the answer since `eclipse { ... }` is used.

Comment: @howlger, here's the answer: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/eclipse-2023-12-buildship-incorrect-classpath-when-importing-test-utils-from-project-library/47970/4
Why removing 'eclipse' plugin?

Comment: So this answer is 100% by [Ole Osterhagen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15790604/ole-osterhagen) and 0% by you. Taking someone else's answer for your own is quite unfair and [not allowed on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Hey man, did you read the first line that I wrote? "I've got the answers in gradle forums". I'm not taking someone else's answer for my own. I just thought that it would have been useful for other people to have the answer, so I wroted it down.

Comment: Hey man, did you read [_How to reference material written by others_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)? "If you copy content that you did not create [...], make sure you do all of the following: Provide a link to the original page or answer, [...],    Provide the name of the original author". I just thought Ole Osterhagen wrote it down, not you. You just copied it without even paying attention to the useful link at the end.

Comment: I think you are going pretty far with your accusations. Anyway feel free to think what you want, I added the link to the original answer. To me it's enough

Comment: I think it's [very unprofessional to get personal](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). Be aware, if someone would have flagged your answer, a moderator may have temporarily suspended your account based on the facts of which you now feel accused. I made Ole Osterhagen's answer a quote to prevent it from being deleted.